# How do I rename a file in PHP when the file is in a different directory than the script?

Tags: php, rename

I am trying to rename a file that is in a separate directory using PHP. This is what I have tried.

```
<?php

//file i want to change
$file_dir = '/home/name/here/myfile.txt';

//directory of script
$cur_dir = '/home/name/there/myhandler.php';

//change directory to location of file to be renamed
chdir('/home/name/here/');

//change file name
rename($file_dir, 'newfilename.txt');

?>
```

However, I get an error that it is still looking for the file in the old directory.

```
rename($file_dir, newfilename.txt): No such file or directory in /home/name/there/myhandler.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying the correct path for the newname

```
//change file name
rename('/home/name/here/myfile.txt', '/home/name/here/newfile.txt');
```

Comment: This worked, for some reason in all of the examples I found it had the code as `rename('full/file/path/name.txt', 'newname.txt')`

Answer (score 0):

$file_dir needs to be the directory name, not the file name for the chdir to work.  You don't need the script directory, or you could use __DIR__

```
<?php

//file i want to change
$file_dir = '/home/name/here';

//change directory to location of file to be renamed
chdir($file_dir);

//change file name
rename('filename.txt', 'newfilename.txt');

?>
```

Comment: I actually did it that way in my code, just didn't add it here for brevity. I will correct it!